# Многопоточность C++ с записью в файл

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Хоче реализовать подобие Worker Pool из Go но на С++, подскажите как лучше это реализовать.
Сами потоки ниепеих данных не получают, но нужно записывать данные в текстовай файл построчно. Сейчас просто пишу в 14 файлов, а потом просто их объединяю.
Порядок строк не важен, главное чтобы они не смешивались с данными из других тредов.

Comment: Можно создать отдельный класс, который будет отвечать за запись в файл. С очередью, из которой он будет считывать строки. Классы с данными через критическую область будут заполнять очередь.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Забыл уточнить, я с крестами так себе знаком, хотя про "критическую область" почитал ещё до написания вопроса. Можно ли где то посмотреть это в виде примеров?

Comment: Пример с двумя потоками: [ссылка](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/parallel/concrt/how-to-implement-various-producer-consumer-patterns?view=msvc-170)